# Cross browser scrolling events in iframe - preventDefault and stopPropagation not acting as expected

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser, scroll

I currently have something like this (jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FEQP6/3/):

```
...
<body>
    <iframe>
        ...
        <body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="scroll">
                   [scroll content]
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        ...
    </iframe>
<body>
...
```

*The problem:* When the scrollbar of the "scroll" div reaches the top or bottom, the scrolling "bubbles" up to the outer page. This seems strange on its own; I thought events within an iframe are supposed to be contained itself.

Anyways, it seems that generally the way around this is to use something like

```
someParentElement.addEventListener("mousewheel",scrollHandler,false)
```

(or the Firefox non-standard events) and then in scrollHandler, use stopPropagation() and/or preventDefault(). But this is where things get weird.

In chrome, it works, but oddly so - I can get listeners to detect mousewheel events originating in the iframe *from outside the iframe*, and stopping the propagation there prevents the page from scrolling. It almost seems like Chrome has 2 event targets, one in the context of the iframe document and one in the context of the outer page's document.

In Firefox and IE, I can't detect scroll events outside the iframe (as I would expect). But when I try to use stopPropagation in the "wrapper" div, the whole page still scrolls. When I use preventDefault in the "wrapper" div, then neither the "scroll" div nor the outer page will scroll at all. Firefox side note: when scrolling context changes from div to page, it "sticks" in FF, but this isn't good enough.

Although I use jquery briefly in the jsfiddle, a solution without it would be preferable. Also, the actual content of the iframe is dynamic, so I'm also hoping to find a solution that can be applied to some kind of container div rather than the actual scrolling div.

Comment: In chrome, it doesn't reach the iframe container until you're at the top or bottom of the div, at which point you actually are scrolling the iframe (even if it can't scroll) which is why the container event is happening in chrome. i suspect the same thing is happening in the other browsers. Inspect the e.target in each case(http://jsfiddle.net/FEQP6/4/), it will always be the iframe when the event occurs in the parent page, not the div.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I didn't realize that was what was happening in Chrome. But it does not seem to be the same behavior for FF and IE. I added listeners on the iframe, and they are never triggered in those browsers (http://jsfiddle.net/FEQP6/5/). It seems that if the cursor is over the iframe, the target is exclusively in the iframe document. But if I put the listener on the iframe document or anything wrapping the scrolling div (for the bubbling phase), neither it nor the outer page will scroll (when the cursor is over the iframe).

Comment: Have same issue and still looking for a solution :(